# Htaccess issue in ssl

Tags: .htaccess

I'm getting .htaccess issue, If I'm using my htaccess in ssl then is not working and its showing 404 not found error.
In the normal http:// mode its working fine but if I'm using https:// it is not working here .

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?first_argu=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?first_argu=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?first_argu=$1&second_argu=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?key=$1&second_argu=$2
```

I'm facing this issue when I bought ssl for my domain. I think this is a issue of my htacess file.someone please check my .htaceess code so that it can resolved ?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have .htaccess allowed for https? Typical if running vhosts you need to add `AllowOverride All` there too. under the `<VirtualHost *:443>`

Comment: nothing I see in those Rewrites that relates to SSL or would affect SSL. whatever's causing a 404 for your https request is happening before or after those rewrites. what's your error log say for the 404?

Comment: It is showing 404 not found..